# Safari on ipad, how to tell browser to ignore mobile stylesheet

Tags: safari, ipad

How can I specify through the browser when to use the mobile stylesheet for a website, and when not to.

This is a specific issue for me on the ipad running Safari.

If this can't be done through the browswer, are any generic User-Agent spoofing tools for ipad that I can employ to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

[UserAgent Faker](http://moreinfo.thebigboss.org/moreinfo/depiction.php?file=uafakerData) for jailbroken devices (in Cydia) changes the User Agent to ones of a desktop browser. Probably some third party browsers too, e.g. [User Agent Browser](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/user-agent-browser-simply/id414229165?mt=8) (free ad supported or $.99 to remove the ads), but haven't used them.

Comment: This did work very well.  But it's pretty annoying that I have to go to jailbreak tools for this sort of thing.

Comment: I assume that Apple doesn't want people to mess up with Mobile Safari, that's why there is no UA changing progmam in the App store. Bot that doesn't prevent third-party browsers for non-jailbroken phones/ipads that support that. But if you have already jailbroken your ipad, it's just a small app to add.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - get the [Journey web browser](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/journey-web-browser/id317286301?mt=8) and fake whatever user agent you prefer without needing to jailbreak your device.

It's a great second browser in it's own right, but the UA flexibility is worth far more than the cost of the app to me.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot.  I would have thought that the safari browser would at least have a switch for specifying safari or safari mobile.

Comment: Desktop Safari has this sort of debug switch coded with a user interface, but not the mobile version.